# How to use \cancel with Shiny MathJax

Tags: r, shiny, mathjax

I’m writing a shiny app that includes `\cancel` in the MathJax. I can’t figure out how to get it to work. Based on the link below, I guess I have to load the `cancel` TeX extension but I can’t figure out how.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  withMathJax(),
  div("$$1+2=3$$"), #Works
  div("$$\\cancel{10a}$$") #Doesnt work
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[Link](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/extensions/cancel.html)
[image: Problem]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```r
library(shiny)

js <- "
window.MathJax = {
  loader: {load: ['[tex]/cancel']},
  tex: {packages: {'[+]': ['cancel']}}
};
"

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(async="", src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"),
    tags$script(HTML(js))
  ),
  div("$$1+2=3$$"), 
  div("$$\\cancel{10a}$$") 
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: This is great but does not work if you feed text ("Equation 1: $$1+1=2$$") into renderUI. Any idea how to make that work as well?

Comment: @MagnusNordmo Please open a new question and I'll answer. This question is not related to extension loading.